# error: could not lock config file H://.gitconfig: File exists

Tags: git

When I try to clone my project in VS 2017, Im getting the below error

> Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access
>   'https://github.com/XXX/XXProject.git/': Failed to connect to
>   github.com port 443: Timed out

And I'am getting below error when I try to set proxy in CMD Prompt

git config --global https.proxy http://proxy.xxx.xxx:port

> error: could not lock config file H://.gitconfig: File exists

Softwares used:
VS 2017, 
Git Version 2.17.0

Comment: Maybe you are setting proxy while git pull is running (trying to connect with guthub ). Try to run the command after git pull stops

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that another program has the file open. Try quitting VS and trying the command again. Also quit any other programs that might have the file open (which potentially includes Explorer, if you have a Git plugin for Explorer).